# Problem deleting all records from ms access table

Tags: ms-access-2013

Scenario:
I have a system that has been working for some while.I need to add a new function involving gathering information into a temporary table.I have reduced the problem to the bare essentials described below.This is driving me mad!! What am I doing wrong.

I do the following:

- Create a simple table with just a couple of fields. I don't change any defaults.
- Create a simple form using the form wizard. I don't change any defaults.
- Open the form in design mode and 1) set the default view to split view; 2) specify an ON OPEN event in VBA which just has the one line 'DoCmd.RunSQL ("Delete * from TestTable")'
- Save and close the form
- Open the form and enter a few records
- Close the form
- Open the form. Now I see 1 record #deleted. I can enter 1 record but no more - the new button is not active.
- Close the form.
- Open the form. No records show and I can enter records as expected but next time round I get the #deleted problem.

I seem to have to close and open the form twice to clear things out.

System and usage:

- This is a standalone system.
- The table is not linked although there are other tables in this application that are linked.
- There are no other users.
- Windows 11
- Microsoft Office Professional 2019
- Microsoft® Access® 2019 MSO (Version 2310 Build 16.0.16924.20054) 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

if you might of been using a function with some variables in it like this `function(cat, dog)` the order does mater because if you gave it dog first and then cat last it would switch the two values so then if cat = 1 and dog = 2 then in that order cat would = 2 and dog would = 1. so try flipping them around.